# Is it posible to get the current time from GPS

Tags: android, gps

I'm seeing in [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#getTime%28%29) that the object Location has a method `getTime()`.

In my app, I need the server time, but sometimes, app can be offline, so I have no choice to get cel time. I would gladly use Location.getTime, but it is not clear to me where this time is coming from?

The Cel or the GPS Satelite???

Is it a reliable data for getting the current hour when app is offline?

Answer (score 3):

As discussed [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7017069/gps-time-in-android?noredirect=1&lq=1), `Location.getTime()` returns either

- the device time (`System.currentTimeMillis()`) if `Location.getProvider().equals(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)`

or

- the GPS (satellite) time (in milliseconds but with 1s precision) if `Location.getProvider().equals(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)`

Since the GPS location determination is based on the knowledge of the precise time, I would say it is at least as reliable as the time you would get from a server.
You can apply your local time zone to the GPS timestamp to get a human readable time, which sould be equal to a properly synced device time (in my case most of the devices where not, so it was even better to use the GPS time).

Answer (score 0):

It is useful when you don't need a very precise time and you just want to know the date only regardless to precise time. Since as the documentation says:

> All locations generated by the LocationManager are guaranteed to have
>   a valid UTC time, however remember that the system time may have
>   changed since the location was generated.

Also take a look at getElapsedRealtimeNanos() it seems to be more precise.

Comment: yes, but the question is : where is this time coming from

Comment: You should read this article, very simple and helpful: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/GPS_disciplined_oscillator

Comment: And don't forget that some devices has A-GPS which may depend on a different way to calculate location not only on satellites but also it uses WiFi networks and nearby devices. I prefer also you take a look to this article: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7017069/gps-time-in-android