# How to get current date even if phone date was not current?

Tags: java, android, date, time

I wanna get the real date in my app, when user offline.
How can I get this from GPS or BTS or something else?

Comment: Check this out. (second answer, not the accepted one)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7017069/gps-time-in-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_LOW);
criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_LOW);
criteria.setAltitudeRequired(false);
criteria.setBearingRequired(false);

locationManager = (LocationManager)context.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
```

And here you go with `location.getTime()`

You can also add `locationListener` to get location updates because `getLastKnownLocation` can return null (see this [GPS-time in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7017069/gps-time-in-android) answer)