# android gnss time for synchronization

Tags: android, time, gps

what is the best way to get the time stamp from GNSS?
I want to use just Galileo OR (GPS AND Glonass)?
At the moment I use

`Date gps_time = new Date(location.getTime());`
but realized it just gives me the time of the fix.
I'm not sure how to get the gps time over location manager...

in [GPS-time in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7017069/gps-time-in-android) there is an example delivering gps time but without milliseconds. But I need them too.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GPS-time in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7017069/gps-time-in-android)

Comment: Right, this helped to get the time. But is there e difference if the phone uses Glonass or GPS? Both areusing different time basis.
Older phones can't use the GNSS interface

Comment: Not sure if you found this: https://www.gsa.europa.eu/system/files/reports/gnss_raw_measurement_web_0.pdf

Answer (score 0):

the ESA pdf and the test program GSPtest helped me.

Just newer phones are able to give GNSS raw measurement back. So with a new phone I took 
`time = (long)(( clock.getTimeNanos() - ( clock.getFullBiasNanos() + (clock.hasBiasNanos() ? clock.getBiasNanos() : 0) ) )/1000000);`
to get milliseconds and add epoch delta between unix time start and gps time start `EPOCH_DELTA = 315964800000L` 
and the leap seconds (in milliseconds 18000).

That's it. (I think)